# Versioning through content negotiation in mvc

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services, model-view-controller

I have two get API with the same request, path, and response out of which one already exists and the other one which is created new.

```
  @GET
  @Path("/{id}/export")
  public Response exportVersion1(@PathParam("id") String id, @QueryParam("format") final String format)

  @GET
  @Path("/{id}/export")
  @Consumes({"application/vnd.com.abc.v2+json"})
  public Response exportVersion2(@PathParam("id") String id, @QueryParam("format") final String format)
```

On giving content type as application/vnd.com.abc.v2+json I am able to call the second API but if no content type is given, then also the second one gets called.

I want to make the first one as default and don't want to change/add to it as it is bound to UI used by the client. I can only make changes to the second API, please give any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set default content type. For spring 5 this will be:

```
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN); 
}
```